# Center unknown on floated element

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I'm working on creating modular tiles that require a graphic to the right of text centered vertically within a tile.

I can't seem to get the centered graphic to behave. This is what I have so far...

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<!--Tile 1-->
<div class="four columns">
    <div class="tile round-border">
        <div class="row container clearfix">
            <div class="nine columns">
                <h2>Headline</h2>
                <p class="body-copy">Body Text</p>
                <a href="#">Action</a>
            </div>
            <div class="three columns absolute-center">
                <div>IMAGE</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.absolute-center{
    display: inline-block!important;
    text-align: center;
}

.absolute-center>div{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by adding a table class to the parent.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff
}
hr {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc
}
a {
  color: #069;
  text-decoration: none
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline
}
.clearfix {
  overflow: hidden
}
.absolute-center {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.table {
  display: table!important;
}
.table > div {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
}
.container {
  padding: 20px
}
.round-border {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px
}
.columns {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0
}
.three {
  width: 25%
}
.four {
  width: 33.33%
}
.nine {
  width: 75%
}
.row:after,
.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden
}
* html .row,
* html .clearfix {
  height: 1%
}
.row,
.clearfix {
  display: inline-block
}
.row,
.clearfix {
  display: block
}
h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: .5em
}
.body-copy {
  line-height: 1.4em;
  margin-bottom: .7em
}
.tile {
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="four columns">
  <div class="tile round-border">
    <div class="row container clearfix table">
      <div class="nine columns">
        <h2>Headline</h2>
        <p class="body-copy">Body Text</p>
        <a href="#">Action</a>
      </div>
      <div class="three columns absolute-center">
        <div>IMAGE</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to be sure that the two columns make the same height for this.
It'll be easier if you don't use columns on it, as you won't be able to do this on floating elements.

The problem is that you can't be sure about the height of your container. This isn't an easy thing in CSS.

Here's a way to do it

```css
.tile {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.tile__content {
    margin-right: 45px; /* width of your image */
}

.tile__image {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
}

.tile__image img, .strut {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.strut {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile round-border">
    <div class="tile__content">
        <h1>Test</h1>
        More height !<br />
        Pliz !
    </div>
    <div class="tile__image">
        <div class="strut"></div><!--
        --><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/CornerStone/PNG/download%20off.png" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Completely width and height adaptable.

Answer (score 1):

just added position :absolute and top :44% in class :.three see demo: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r7awm8on/)

```css
/*
*
* Global
*
*/
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box
}

ul li{
    list-style:none;
}

ol li{
    margin-left: 1.3em;
}

body {
    margin:0;
    font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#333;
    background-color:#fff
}

sup, sub {
   vertical-align: baseline;
   position: relative;
   top: -0.4em;
}
sub { top: 0.4em; }

.pull-right {
    float:right!important
}

.pull-left {
    float:left!important
}

.hide {
    display:none!important
}

.show {
    display:block!important
}

.invisible {
    visibility:hidden
}

hr {
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border:0;
    border-top:1px solid #ccc
}

.afix {
    position:fixed
}

a {
    color:#069;
    text-decoration:none
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline
}

.clearfix {
    overflow:hidden
}

.center-text {
    text-align:center
}

.text-replace {
    text-indent:100%;
    display:block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden
}

.absolute-center{
    display: inline-block!important;
    text-align: center;
}

.absolute-center>div{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/*
*
* Foundation
*
*/
#wrapper {
    width:978px;
    margin:20px auto;
    position:relative
}

.container {
    padding:20px
}

.section {
    margin-bottom:20px
}

.shadow {
    box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)
}

.hero-space {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:350px
}

.bottom-border,.hero-space {
    border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc
}

.top-border {
    border-top:solid 1px #ccc
}

.round-border,.shadow {
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px
}

.round {
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px
}

/*
*
* Sticky-Bar
*
*/
.sticky-bar {
    width:100%;
    background:#fff;
    z-index:99
}

/*
*
* 8-Column Grid System
*
*/
.column,.columns {
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    margin:0
}

.one {
    width:8.333%
}

.two {
    width:16.66%
}

.three {
    width:25%;
 position:absolute;
 top:44%;
}

.four {
    width:33.33%
}

.five {
    width:41.66%
}

.six {
    width:50%
}

.seven {
    width:58.33%
}

.eight {
    width:66.66%
}

.nine {
    width:75%
}

.ten {
    width:83.33%
}

.eleven {
    width:91.66%
}

.twelve {
    width:100%
}

.fifths{
    width:20%
}

.gutter .column, .gutter .columns{
    padding:0 10px;
    
}

.column-row:after,.row:after,.clearfix:after {
    content:".";
    display:block;
    height:0;
    clear:both;
    visibility:hidden
}

* html .column-row,* html .row,* html .clearfix {
    height:1%
}
/****change*****/
.column-row,.row,.clearfix {
    display:inline-block;
 
}
/***change*****/
.column-row,.row,.clearfix {
    display:block
}

/*
*
* Backgrounds
*
*/
.gradient-down {
    background:#f4f4f4;
/* Old browsers */
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#f4f4f4 0%,#fff 100%);
/* FF3.6+ */
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,#f4f4f4),color-stop(100%,#fff));
/* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#f4f4f4 0%,#fff 100%);
/* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top,#f4f4f4 0%,#fff 100%);
/* Opera 11.10+ */
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#f4f4f4 0%,#fff 100%);
/* IE10+ */
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom,#f4f4f4 0%,#fff 100%);
/* W3C */
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f4f4f4',endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0)
/* IE6-9 */
}

.gradient-up {
    background:#f4f4f4;
/* Old browsers */
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#f4f4f4 100%);
/* FF3.6+ */
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,#fff),color-stop(100%,#f4f4f4));
/* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#f4f4f4 100%);
/* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#f4f4f4 100%);
/* Opera 11.10+ */
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#f4f4f4 100%);
/* IE10+ */
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff 0%,#f4f4f4 100%);
/* W3C */
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fff',endColorstr='#f4f4f4',GradientType=0)
/* IE6-9 */
}

.gradient-diagonal {
    background:#fff;
/* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,#fff 0%,#f4f4f4 100%);
/* FF3.6+ */
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right bottom,color-stop(0%,#fff),color-stop(100%,#f4f4f4));
/* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,#fff 0%,#f4f4f4 100%);
/* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background:-o-linear-gradient(-45deg,#fff 0%,#f4f4f4 100%);
/* Opera 11.10+ */
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,#fff 0%,#f4f4f4 100%);
/* IE10+ */
    background:linear-gradient(135deg,#fff 0%,#f4f4f4 100%);
/* W3C */
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff',endColorstr='#f4f4f4',GradientType=1)
/* IE6-8 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}

.solid-blue {
    background:#067ab4
}

.solid-blue,.solid-blue a,.solid-black,.solid-black a {
    color:#fff
}

.solid-black {
    background:#333
}

.solid-grey {
    background:#f4f4f4
}

/*
*
* Browser Error
*
*/
.browsererror {
    background:#fffde8;
    width:100%
}

.browsererror h2 {
    margin-bottom:5px
}

.browsererror ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-right:15px;
    line-height:18px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:url(../images/error-sprite.png) no-repeat top left
}

.browsererror ul li a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding-right:17px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:url(../images/error-sprite.png) no-repeat right -76px
}

.close a {
    background:#e9e7d0;
    padding:15px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:81px
}

.close a:hover {
    background:#e3e1cb
}

.close a span {
    width:19px;
    height:19px;
    text-indent:100%;
    display:block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:url(../images/error-sprite.png) no-repeat left bottom
}

/*
*
* Typography
*
*/
h1 {
    font-weight:100;
    font-size:32px;
    margin-bottom:.5em
}

h2 {
    font-weight:300;
    font-size:20px;
    margin-bottom:.5em
}

h3 {
    font-weight:900;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-bottom:.5em;
    color:#999
}

.body-copy {
    line-height:1.4em;
    margin-bottom:.7em
}

.sub-heading {
    font-size:15px;
    color:#666;
    margin-bottom:.5em
}

.block-quote {
    border-left:3px solid #ccc;
    padding-left:10px;
    margin-left:10px
}

.price{
    color:#ff7200;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin-bottom: .05em;
}

.legal{
    font-size: 10px;
    color:#666;
}
/*
*
* Forms
*
*/
.form-title {
    font-weight:900;
    margin:0 10px 10px 0
}

input[type=radio],input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label,input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    background-position:bottom left;
    color:#333
}

.form label {
    color:#999;
    padding-left:20px;
    height:15px;
    display:block;
    line-height:17px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:0 0;
    font-size:12px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.form li{
    margin-bottom:10px

}

.radio + label {
    background-image:url(../images/sprite-radio.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

.checkbox + label {
    background-image:url(../images/sprite-check.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;


}

.form label:hover {
    color:#333
}

.form-hrz li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:5px
}

/*
*
* Buttons
*
*/
.btn {
    font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
    color:#069;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:10px 15px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    display:inline-block;
    font-weight:200
}

/*Size*/
.btn-lg {
    font-size:20px;
    padding:15px 20px
}

.btn-md {
    font-size:15px;
    padding:10px 15px
}

.btn-sm {
    font-size:12px;
    padding:10px 15px
}

.btn-xsm {
    font-size:11px;
    padding:5px 10px
}

/*Color*/
.btn-primary {
    background:#067ab4;
    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,#5EACD4 0%,#067ab4 100%);
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#5EACD4 0%,#067ab4 100%);
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0,#5EACD4),color-stop(1,#067ab4));
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#5EACD4 0%,#067ab4 100%);
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#5EACD4 0%,#067ab4 100%);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#5EACD4 0%,#067ab4 100%);
    border-color:#067ab4;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}

.btn-primary:hover {
    background:#067ab4;
    color:#fff;
    cursor:pointer
}

.btn-primary:active {
    background:#0986b8;
    color:#fff
}

.btn-default {
    background:#fff;
    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff 0%,#f4f4f4 100%);
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#f4f4f4 100%);
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0,#fff),color-stop(1,#f4f4f4));
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#f4f4f4 100%);
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#f4f4f4 100%);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#f4f4f4 100%);
    border-color:#ccc;
    color:#069
}

.btn-default:hover {
    background:#f4f4f4;
    cursor:pointer
}

.btn-default:active {
    background:#eee
}

.btn-disabled {
    background:#f4f4f4;
    border-color:#ccc;
    color:#999
}

.btn-disabled:hover {
    cursor:default
}

.btn-none {
    background:transparent;
    border:none;
    color:#069
}

.btn-none:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:underline
}

/*
*
* Tabs
*
*/
.tabs ul li {
    text-align:center
}

.tabs ul li+li {
    border-left:solid 1px #ccc
}

.tabs ul li a {
    padding:15px;
    display:block;
    color:#666;
    background:#f4f4f4;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc
}

.tabs ul li a:hover {
    color:#333;
    background:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom-width:3px;
    padding-bottom:12px
}

.tabs ul .active a {
    color:#067ab4;
    background:#fff;
    border-bottom:3px solid #067ab4;
    padding-bottom:12px
}

.tabs ul .active a:hover {
    color:#067ab4;
    background:#fff;
    border-bottom:3px solid #067ab4;
    padding-bottom:12px;
    cursor:default
}

.tab-content {
    display:none;
}

.tab-stage .active {
    display:block
}

.tabs .icon {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto 10px;
    background:url() no-repeat bottom center
}

.tabs .active .icon {
    background-position:top center
}

/*
*
* Tag Cloud
*
*/
.tag-cloud li {
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px
}

.tag-cloud li a {
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    background:#067ab4;
    color:#fff;
    border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px
}

.tag-cloud li a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#069;
    color:#fff
}

/*
*
* Meters
*
*/
.meter .label li {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:2px 5px 2px 0;
    margin-bottom:5px
}

.meter .label li+li {
    padding-left:10px;
    border-left:1px solid #ccc
}

.meter .bar-container {
    background:#eee;
    border-radius:20px;
    -moz-border-radius:20px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
    margin-right:10px
}

.meter .bar {
    height:20px;
    border-radius:20px;
    -moz-border-radius:20px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px
}

.meter-small .bar {
    height:7px
}

/*Green Bar*/
.green .bar {
    background:#6ebb1f
}

.green .status {
    padding-left:0;
    line-height:20px;
    font-size:15px
}

/*Yellow Bar*/
.yellow .bar {
    background:#fc0
}

.yellow .status {
    padding-left:25px;
    background:url(../images/alert-sprite.png) no-repeat left top;
    line-height:20px;
    font-size:15px
}

/*Red Bar*/
.red .bar {
    background:#c00
}

.red .status {
    padding-left:25px;
    background:url(../images/alert-sprite.png) no-repeat left bottom;
    line-height:20px;
    font-size:15px
}

/*Null Bar*/
.null .bar {
    background:#666
}

.null .status {
    line-height:20px;
    font-size:15px
}

/*
*
* Tiles
*
*/
.tile{
    margin: 5px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sales-tile{
    height: 246px;
}

.tile .tag{
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
    z-index:2;
    right:-3px;
    top:-3px;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(../images/tag-sprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.tile .collapse{
    overflow: hidden;
}

.compare{
    background:#e6f1f7;
    border-color:#067ab4;
}


.fourGLTE-tag{background-position:0 0;}
.fourG-tag{background-position:0 -65px;}
.webonly-tag{background-position:0 -130px;}
.webprice-tag{background-position:0 -195px;}


/*
*
* Stars
*
*/
.stars{
    height:10px;
    background-image: url(../images/stars-sprite.png);
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
}

.no-star{background-position: 50% -100px;}
.half-star{background-position: 50% -90px;}
.one-star{background-position: 50% -80px;}
.one-half-star{background-position: 50% -70px;}
.two-star{background-position: 50% -60px;}
.two-half-star{background-position: 50% -50px;}
.three-star{background-position: 50% -40px;}
.three-half-star{background-position: 50% -30px;}
.four-star{background-position: 50% -20px;}
.four-half-star{background-position: 50% -10px;}
.five-star{background-position: 50% 0;}


/*
*
* Notes
*
*/

.reminder{background: #ffffcc; border-color: #cccc99;}
.success{background: #e4f7da; border-color: #6ebb1f; color: #529442;}
.alert{background: #fae5e5; border-color: #cc0000; color: #cc0000;}
.well{background: #f4f4f4; border-color: #ccc;}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<!--Tile 1-->
<div class="four columns">
    <div class="tile round-border">
        <div class="row container clearfix">
            <div class="nine columns">
                <h2>Headline</h2>
                <p class="body-copy">Body text will display here.</p>
                <a href="#">Action</a>
            </div>
            <div class="three columns absolute-center">
                <div>Image</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may define the height for that div:

```
.absolute-center>div{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100px;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vsya21bL/3/)

Comment: the height needs to be variable.

Comment: Then you may use height: 100%; instead but for this make sure your parent height is fixed...

Comment: both the image container and the parent container are variable heights. I tried setting the height to 100%, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Yes, I already told you that won't work if the parent height is not set. To make it work you use parent and parent divs until html,body to be 100%.